# both vertical and horizontal smooth scrolling between anchors

Tags: javascript, html, scroll, smoothing

I want to do the smooth scrolling, using anchors, on the same page. 
All my anchors are spread out on a page at different horizontal or/and vertical levels.
I got this code below, which only works well with scrolling vertically, and doesn't work with scrolling horizontally. 
What should I do to make the the scrolling go vertically and horizontally at the same time?

```
$(function() {

// scroll handler
var scrollToAnchor = function( id ) {

// grab the element to scroll to based on the name
var elem = $("a[name='"+ id +"']");

// if that didn't work, look for an element with our ID
if ( typeof( elem.offset() ) === "undefined" ) {
  elem = $("#"+id);
}

// if the destination element exists
if ( typeof( elem.offset() ) !== "undefined" ) {

  // do the scroll
  $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: elem.offset().top
  }, 1000 );

}
};

// bind to click event
$("a").click(function( event ) {

// only do this if it's an anchor link
if ( $(this).attr("href").match("#") ) {

  // cancel default event propagation
  event.preventDefault();

  // scroll to the location
  var href = $(this).attr('href').replace('#', '')
  scrollToAnchor( href );

}

});

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should animate the scrollLeft property as well...

```
$('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: elem.offset().top,
          scrollLeft: elem.offset().left
}, 1000 );
```

Or use the jquery [scrollTo](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/) plugin.

Comment: Ah yes, I messed it up: there was a typo in my code to add the left and that's why it didn't work. Yea I'm also looking at scrollTo plugin. Thanks!